# Underground Shortest Path - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

So I want to make a program to find the shortest path between 2 train stations. What would you suggest is the best way to represent the train lines, where they intersect and search for this? My current thoughts are Adjacency Matrix or List however, I'm not sure as not all adjacent points are linked.

Eg. 
The train lines would look like this:

- Grey Line stations - Waterloo, Southwark,  London Bridge
- Black Line stations - Kennington, Oval, Borough, London Bridge
- Black line 2 Stations - Kennington, Waterloo, Embankment
- Brown Line Stations -   Elephant & Castle, Waterloo, Embankment.

if I wanted to to from Oval to Southwark for example, I would go:

- Oval  to   Kennington on Black Line  (then switch the Blank line 2)
- Kennington  to  Waterloo  (Then switch to Grey line)
- Waterloo to Southwark.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortest paths problem. Since you're interested in shortest time, then just use the durations in place of distances. Dijkstra's algorithm is a common approach for solving these types of problems. It is well documented on the Internet. If you intend to generate a timetable of all trips, then you should look into the Floyd-Warshall algorithm since it can generate solutions for all pairs of stations.

Both of these methods will require you to model the rail system as a graph. The edge weights will be the times to travel between stations. For stations with multiple lines, you could use multiple nodes and edges with a weight of 4 between them.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the travelling salesman problem, for which there is no known closed solution, other than trying all possible paths. Note that the number of such paths increases exponentially with the number of stations, so it becomes computationally very expensive quite rapidly.

Also, you have to decide whether you want the shortest distance between the stations, or the shortest travel time between them.

Comment: I'll be wanting shortest travel time.
the rules are that it's 2 minutes between stations on the same line.
4 minutes to switch lines (if the station exists on multiple lines)
and 0 minutes if the station is on 2 branches of the same line (eg Kennington is on both Blank lines.  So the Oval   to  Southwark example I gave, would take 10 minutes)